# System Backup taking to long to run

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, backup

0System Backup Excluding Media & Upgrade Takes Too Long and Installation Wizard Pops Up

So I started the upgrades from current 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.3.4 and checked system backup and maintenance mode check-boxes. `500 Error` fixed with changing permissions to `755`. Installation Wizard popped up on my domain After I fixed `500 Error`. Back up is still in process.

Screenshot is attached [image]

Comment: Look for Apache logs to define what happened and why 500 is there. Seems like it is max_execution time limited. Backup will run for a log time anyway and there is no way to speed it up. 

However, you can do it manually (via ssh or any hosting-tool) and than try to upgrade without magento-generated backups. It would be 10 times faster for sure.

Comment: You can contact your hosting provider to give you a full backup of your site and if you can upgrade via FTP it would be faster.  Your 500 error is most likely a timeout and you can increase this in your .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You will want to increase your Max Execution time for the upgrade

You can do this in your htaccess or in your php.ini file

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

You can use "0" or "18000"

You will also want to look at the memory that PHP is using

```
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
```

Both of these values can be set then reset after the upgrade

The easiest way to find the values from the frontend it to create a file called

phpinfo.php and include the following code

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

That will show you everything you need to know!